# Why is change to iptables not taking effect?

Tags: linux, vpn, proxy, iptables, openvpn

Im trying to setup OpenVPN to use Tor as a proxy in Liberte. When I run openvpn as root, I get the following response:

```
Tue May 13 15:15:18 2014 Attempting to establish TCP connection with 127.0.0.1:9050 [nonblock]
Tue May 13 15:15:20 2014 TCP: connecto to 127.0.0.1:9050 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: No route to host
```

I assume that this is due to the following setup:

```
# Tor access via SOCKS only for main user and Privoxy
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner ${luser} --syn -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner privoxy  --syn -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT       -p tcp                               --syn -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 9050 -j LOGREJECT
```

Because when I try to run openvpn as the regular user (anon) it connects without any issues. Instead it runs into some other permission conflicts later in the execution.

So I tried to run the following:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner root  --syn -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT
/etc/init.d/iptables save
/etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

And sure enough the changes show up when I do iptables -L.

But I still get the same error when I try to run openvpn. So why will the changes not take effect?

Comment: It's rather unclear what you're doing.  Are you trying to do this: [you] -> [OpenVPN] -> [Tor] -> [Destination Site] or something else?

Comment: No. I am trying to do: Me -> OpenVPN -> Tor -> VPN server -> Destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:

When you add a new rule using `iptables`, it tacks on the rule at the end of the chain.

So your chain probably looks like this after you issue that command:

```
# Tor access via SOCKS only for main user and Privoxy
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner ${luser} --syn -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner privoxy  --syn -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT       -p tcp                               --syn -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 9050 -j LOGREJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner root  --syn -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 9050 -j ACCEPT
```

The root-owned packet is getting tripped up in the LOGREJECT rule since it appears ahead of the final ACCEPT rule.  You need to issue the 4th line before the 3rd.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That makes sense. And it actually occurred to me, too. But I have no idea how I would go about removing the 3rd line before inserting the new one. I'll see if I can figure it out and accept your answer if it works out.